# Making Data Structure Persistent

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, tree

I read a file in JAVA and based on the users specifications, I convert the data in to a Linked List or a Tree, but how can I save the data in to the file (as a data structure), so that next time I read the data I do not have to make extra effort to parse the file.

Comment: You can use serialization for writing the tree in a file and then deserialize it when you want to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can save the data like this into file it is not a linked list but it will help to understand

```
//save persons
public void savePersons(){
try{
    PersonsInfo p;
    String line;
    FileWriter fw= new FileWriter("input.txt");
    PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(fw);
    for (int i=0 ; i<persons.size();i++){
        p =(PersonsInfo)persons.get(i);
        line = p.getName() +","+ p.getAddress() +","+ p.getPhoneNum();
        pw.println(line);
    }
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    fw.close();
} catch (IOException ioEx){
System.out.println(ioEx);   
}
```

> and you can retrieve the data like this and you dont need the parse the file every time

```
public class AddressBook{
ArrayList<PersonsInfo> persons;
public AddressBook (){
    persons = new ArrayList <PersonsInfo> ();
    loadPersons();
}
//Load Person
public void loadPersons (){
String tokens[]=null;
String name,address,phoneNum;
try{
    FileReader fr= new FileReader("input.txt");
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line=br.readLine();
    while (line !=null)
    {
        tokens = line.split(",");
        name=tokens[0];
        address=tokens[1];
        phoneNum=tokens[2];
        PersonsInfo p = new PersonsInfo(name,address,phoneNum);
        persons.add(p);
        line = br.readLine();
    }

br.close();
fr.close();

}catch (IOException ioEx) {
        System.out.println(ioEx);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to store the data:

- If you don't want to data to be stored in human readable form then you can go ahead with `Serialization` (example [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/serialization-in-java)). Java will take care of storing/constructing the objects/structures during write/read operations respectively.
- If you want to store the data in human readable form then you can convert the data into let's say `json` and store it in String format. You can use Jackson's `ObjectMapper` class, e.g.:

  `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  YourClass object = new YourClass();
  FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("path_to_file");
  outputStream.write(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object));`

  `//Read
  YourClass persisted = mapper.readValue("path_to_file", YourClass.class);`

  [Here's](http://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/read-write-json-using-jackson-objectmapper-jsonparser-jsongenerator-example) the example and here's [Jackson's](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `serialization` which is a Java feature so very easy to use :

**Save :**

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
try {
      LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();  
      list.add("toto");  list.add("tata");

      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\..\\Doc\\list.ser"));
      oos.writeObject(list);
} catch ... {
}finally (oos.close) ...{
}
```

Of course, if it's not a you change `LinkedList` to whatever you want

---

**Load :**

```
ObjectInputStream ois = null;

try {
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\..\\Doc\\list.ser"));

    final LinkedList<String> list = (LinkedList<String>) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(list.toString());   //[toto,tata]
} catch ... {
}finally (ois.close) ...{
}
```

At writing you use `writeObject` and at reading you use `readObject` + `casting` to the good type (so the order is important, if you write a List then String then Other, you may read List then String then Other)

[`Serialization Details`](https://www.javatpoint.com/serialization-in-java)